# Can admob ad ID be shared on public GitHub repository?

Tags: android, git, github, google-play, admob

I have a private project on Github, an Android app with ads on it. Will there be any issue if I make the project public and the ad IDs be publicly visible?

Comment: of course you run the risk of people using your adID on something that may break Google's AdMob (or whoever you are using) policy. Use gitlab instead of github, their private storage is free.

Comment: Yes you are right. The project is already in a private repository on GitHub, but wasn't sure if I can make it public. Thanks !

Comment: yeah, i mean you can, sure, but that is the risk you face. You can however store those ID's on a server/database and make a call to get it and then store it on the device... but yeah, someone who knows what they are doing can get it from that too.

Comment: Yeah , I was thinking if possible to make a separate file for the ID's and .gitignore the file.

Comment: Yea u can definitely do that!!! Create a java class for all of your constants, and just add the class to your gitignore. Problem solved. Unless u want people to clone it, then I have to send them the file

Comment: I can put on README file the instructions to create and add their own ad ID's. I think that's gonna work. And my ad ID's will be safe in my local machine

Comment: Idk what the purpose of ur app is, but if they use their IDs, then they get paid, you dont

Comment: My app is on play store and the project is to showcase my coding skills and if somebody wants to modify it to their own version I don't mind as long as they don't duplicate the exact app.

Comment: I mean you're allowing them to do that but giving them access to your source code

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to.. Bdw there's another problem the commit history has the ad ID's already.

Comment: Create a new repo. Delete the old is one option

Comment: Right. I think I'll keep this private for now and make another project without ad lol. Thanks for the help bdw. Much appreciated 

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, I see that the best option for you is to store your Ad ID's securely without exposing them through the repository.

You can do this by hiding the keys inside the `BuildConfig` and then excluding the file from `.gitignore`.

You can find the full tutorial on doing that here:

[Storing secret keys in Android](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android)